# Select records based on a column value changing from the last record

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using Sql Server 2008

So I have a Table called States and it has data like this:

```
DateTime                | skID | TZ | DomID | EventName | SKGrpID | State
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-06-08 09:22:54.010 | 1234 | 1  | 222   | 0         | 4321    | 0
2016-06-08 09:22:54.000 | 1234 | 1  | 222   | 3         | 4321    | 3
2016-06-08 09:21:56.000 | 1234 | 1  | 222   | 8         | 4321    | 4
2016-06-08 09:19:00.000 | 1234 | 1  | 222   | 7         | 4321    | 4
2016-06-08 09:18:58.000 | 1234 | 1  | 222   | 4         | 4321    | 4
2016-06-08 09:13:06.000 | 1234 | 1  | 222   | 6         | 4321    | 6
2016-06-08 09:10:42.000 | 1234 | 1  | 222   | 4         | 4321    | 4
2016-06-08 09:10:40.000 | 1234 | 1  | 222   | 1         | 5555    | 1
2016-06-08 09:00:28.003 | 1234 | 1  | 222   | 1         | 4321    | 1
```

Rows can be thought of records for someone answering a phone. If the state is '4' it means they are talking on the phone and if it is anything else then they are not. The oldest records are at the bottom. So the third record at 9:10:42 is the start of a call and the record at 9:13:06 is the end of the call (state changed from 4 to 6.)

Sometimes the call last over multiple events. so on the record for 9:18:58 a call starts and it continues to until the record at 9:21:56 (states start ->4,4,4,3 <-End)

I would like a query that somehow selects the start record and end record, joins them and gets a duration. The issue is I have no idea how I can select based off the state changing from a 4 to something else. I am also struggling to figure out how to select each of the start of each call (the start records would be a record with a state of 4 and the preceding record being something else (so like States 1, 4, 3, 6 , 4, 5 would be the second and 5th records would be call starts and 3 and 6 would be the ends of the calls. ))

ideal result would be something like

```
StartTime, EndTime, Duration, skID, TZ, DomID, SKGrpID, StartEvent, StartState, EndEvent, EndState
```

I am able to accomplish this currently in python by just querying all rows and then making dicts and matching the calls that way but I would like to do as much as possible in the SQL. Is doing this kind of select even possible?

Comment: It is possible. But on Stack Overflow you're supposed to show what you've tried. But to give you a hint: look up LIMIT 1 and ORDER BY ASC/DESC. Good luck.

Comment: @user3741598 I can post what I have tried, but that's basically a ton of small queries that got nothing like what I want. I have never written a query like this and couldn't even find a good starting point. I understand how limit works but not how will that help if there can be multiple calls in a day.

Comment: @user3741598 Realized i put the wrong tag. This is sql-server so i can't even use limit.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

```
select
  max(case when RN = 1 then DateTime end) as StartTime,
  max(case when RN = 2 then DateTime end) as EndTime,
  max(case when RN = 1 then EventName end) as StartEvent,
  max(case when RN = 2 then EventName end) as EndEvent
from
(
  select
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by CallId order by DateTime) as RN
  from
  (
    select
      *,
      sum(CallStatus) over (order by DateTime) as CallId
    from
    (
      select
        *
      from
      (
        select 
          *,
          lag(CallStatus) over (order by DateTime) as PrevCallStatus
        from
        (
          select 
            DateTime,
            State,
            EventName,
            case when State = 4 then 1 else 0 end as CallStatus
          from #Table1
        ) A
      ) B
      where CallStatus != PrevCallStatus 
    ) C
  ) D
) E
group by CallId
```

This starts with the innermost derived table `A` which is used to assign a call status 1/0. Table `B` is used to get the previous value of CallStatus, which is then used to filter out rows that have the same CallStatus. Because CallStatus is 1/0, it can be used in a running total to calculate a separate ID for each call. Because the data from this will always contain 2 rows, row_number is used to assign the rows a number (1=start, 2=end), and this is then used in the final select to get the data separately from start and end rows.

This doesn't have all your fields, but at least it should get you started :)

This assumes you always have an ending record for your calls, and works only in SQL Server 2012 or later. For older versions you'd need to create something a lot more complex for the running total and lag. Most likely a cursor would be the best option then.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! It is sadly SQL Server 2008 version 10.5 so I have to find some way to get past not having the lag function but this at least gave me an idea of how to go about it so thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'StartTime'
     , 'EndTime'
     , 'Duration'
     , 'skID'
     , 'TZ'
     , 'DomID'
     , 'SKGrpID'
     , 'StartEvent'
     , 'StartState'
     , 'EndEvent'
     , 'EndState';
```

If that's not what you meant, please clarify. ;-)

Comment: I don't even have words.